# Add checkboxes on the first column for mark individual rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, datatable

I'm newbie using DataTables and I need to add a first column on my DataTables elements to mark individual rows and don't know how to do this right now so any help will be appreciated. The idea is on `thead` is there is one, where columns legend goes, put a checkbox for select all the rows on the table but also on each `tr` put an individual `checkbox` to allow choice multiples rows but not all. After get this done I need to copy all the marked rows and append to another DataTable if the new one has rows, otherwise is just copy the content from one DT to another DT. The first DT is show on a Twitter Bootstrap modal component and I have a button to copy the selected rows to the second DT which is on the background (outside the Bootstrap modal), can any give me some help or advice? This is the only code I'm using for handle DT:

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(selector)) {
    table = $(selector).DataTable();
    table.clear().draw();
    table.destroy();
}

table = $(selector).DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0, 3]}
    ],
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
    "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
    "pageLength": 5,
    "language": {
        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "sUrl": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Primero",
            "sLast": "Último",
            "sNext": "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    }
});
```

`selector` can be any, ex: `#idTable` or `.classTable` and for HTML table code you can use the one provided by `tables` on Bootstrap site, the mine is just the same but with different data and built on the fly I mean using AJAX to get records from Database. Anyway here is a piece of code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post your code part? with bit of HTML? so that we can guide     you

Comment: @RamzanZafar done, take a look now

Comment: Use `render` to define what is displayed in the first column table cell: [column_render.html](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)